# How to use the child objects in a related list after a soql call in Visual Force

Tags: visualforce, soql, javascript, related-list, relationships

My org has an account object with a related list of Contacts. I am querying for the Contacts from the Account and want to use the data on the Contact object. How can I access fields from the contact objects?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jq$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq$(document).ready(function() {                         
        try{
            sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
            var qr = sforce.connection.query("Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name, Address_Verified_Date__c, Child_Document_Verification_Date__c From Contacts) From account where id = " + "'" + "{!Account.id}" + "'");
            alert('I am here');
            var records = qr.getArray("records");
            alert(records.length);
         }
        catch(err){
            alert(err.message);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you examine the structure of `records`?  I would use `console.log(JSON.stringify(records));` to look at the structure.  I'm not sure how nested records are returned in the result set.

Comment: It's not a JSON string, otherwise I would have used JSON.parse. I found a workable solution though that I will post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
var jq$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq$(document).ready(function() {                         
        try{
            sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
            var qr = sforce.connection.query("Select (Select Id, Name, Address_Verified_Date__c, Child_Document_Verification_Date__c From Contacts) From account where id = " + "'" + "{!Account.id}" + "'");
            var records = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(qr);
            var contacts = [];
            while(records.hasNext()){
                var account = records.next();
                if(account.Contacts){
                    var cit = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(account.Contacts);
                    while(cit.hasNext()){
                        contacts.push(cit.next());
                    }
                }
            }
            alert(contacts.length);
         }
        catch(err){
            alert(err.message);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nice.  Thanks.  Curious if you considered JS Remoting or not?  If so, why did you go with this approach?

Comment: @ArtieBrosius I went with this approach because this project is for a non profit. I wanted a quick and dirty approach instead of needing to write a class and also write tests for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var qr = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name, Address_Verified_Date__c, Child_Document_Verification_Date__c FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id = '{!Account.id}'").getArray("records");
var records = qr[0].Contacts.getArray("records");
```

That will enable you to use the fields within the Contact e.g `records.Address_Verified_Date__c`, `records.Id`, `records.Child_Document_Verification_Date__c`, etc...